# How do I increase stepsize in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

For my computing course, I am asked to solve an ODE, using Euler's method.
My code runs, however, I am now asked the following:

*"Increase N a number of times, according to N=100,200,400,800.... so you can obtain the answers y100,y200,y400,y800...."*

Here's my code:

```
function [xar,yar] = eulsol(a,b,ybouco,N)
h=(b-a)/N;
T=a:h:b;
y(1)=ybouco;
for i = 100:N
    f(i) = -8*y(i) + 0.5*T(i) + (1/16);
    y(i+1) = y(i)+h*f(i);
end
xar=T;
yar=y;
end
```

Can someone help me with obtaining a nice table in MATLAB, which shows me the arrays `x` and `y`, according to an increasing `N` (100,200,400,800....)?

Comment: You can create a vector `Nvect = [100, 200, 400, 800]` and select one vector element at a time in your `for i` loop. Alternatively, you can use an index such as `i_old` and `i_new` with `i_new = i_old * 2` starting with value 100.

Comment: @marsei Thanks! But where in my code should i put the index code (i_new = i_old * 2)?  in my for-loop?

Comment: As a professor of mine used to say, "be creative" - it is your assignment. Good luck.

Comment: Why are you stepping from 100? What is y#00? You said your code runs. But does it give correct results? Please explain your question more. Please comment your code. Please don't feel entitled that others should try to understand your program by reading it line by line. Absolutely don't do that to your future colleagues. SO is not a homework help site. I can assure you no one is eager to do your assignment for you. However, I believe many are happy to help you understand more about implementing numerical methods on matlab. Your question, as far as I can tell, is unrelated to matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define K as the number of steps. In your example, K=4 (N=100,200,400,800). If N=100,200,400,800,1600,3200 then K = 6

Note that the ith element of N correspond to 100*2^(i-1):

```
i = 1 => N = 100 * 2^(1-1) = 100
i = 2 => N = 100 * 2^(2-1) = 200
i = 3 => N = 100 * 2^(3-1) = 400
```

and so on...

So if you want to calculate for N=100,200,400,800, your code should be:

```
function [xar,yar] = eulsol(a,b,ybouco,K)
N_max = 100 * 2^(K-1)
h=(b-a)/N_max;
T=a:h:b;
y(1)=ybouco;
for i = 1:K
    N = 100 * 2^(i-1)
    f(N) = -8*y(N) + 0.5*T(N) + (1/16);
    y(N+1) = y(N)+h*f(N);
end
xar=T;
yar=y;
end
```

This answer if for creating the correct N inside the for loop, but you should review your code! As you can see: for i = 1, you have N = 100 and to calculate F(100) you need y(100), but you don't have y(100), just y(1).
Maybe the correct answer is F(i) = -8*y(i) + 0.5*T(N) + (1/16);
But again, want is T(N)?

Please, as noted by @Argyll , explain what you want, you shouldn't expect people to understand your question from a wrong code.